# Yii2 change redactor box size

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, redactor

I'm using Yii2 Redactor box, extension from: https://github.com/yiidoc/yii2-redactor

I want to change size of the textarea but I don't know how, it not mention in their document. I've tried to edit their css but it didn't work.

Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Redactor is flexibility, It means you just need to set its parent with but itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way you can control the height of the text area:

```
echo $form->field($curriculum,'text')->widget(Widget::className(),[
                            'settings' => [             
                                'lang' => 'en',
                                'minHeight' => 500,
                                'plugins' => [
                                    'fullscreen', 'fontfamily','fontcolor','fontsize','imagemanager',                                       
                                ],
                                'buttons' => [
                                      'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|', 
                                      'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                                      'image', 'table', 'link', '|',
                                      'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule',
                                      '|', 'underline', '|', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'justify'
                                ],
                                'imageUpload'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('program/uploadcurriculumart'),
                                'clipboardUpload'=>true,
                                'clipboardUploadUrl'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('program/uploadcurriculumart'),
                                'imageManagerJson'=>\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('program/getallcurriculumart')
                            ]
                        ],['style' => 'height:500px;'])->label(false);
```

Notice the two arguments: minHeight and also I set the style for the control to have a height of 500px;  Works perfectly.